# Design SQL tables

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a set of business objects, which will need to store properties specific to the object type. I want these properties to be definable by the user at runtime. My solution for that is to have a table for each object type that contains the property keys for that object type.

For example, a user object may have a set of properties: fname, lname, address, phone, SSN. And if desired, that list can be built upon within the application, to now include email.

I then have a set of tables which contain all the possible values for a given property. So I'd have a table containing all addresses, a table containing all emails, etc. These may be used by different object types, and some property keys may have multiple values. If a a new property is created, a new table to contain that new set of values would also be created.

The problem I'm having is mapping out everything, in such a way that I can identify the value of each property, for each instance, of each object.

Any suggestions on what I might be missing, what I should be looking into, or any other solutions to the problem would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Disclaimer: I'm a relativity new self taught programmer. Forgive any ignorance or shortcoming.

Comment: This is in fact an excellent idea: treat tables as domains. But there is a limit to it: would you want to have a table with first names, and let the *fact table* refer to it? Or Date Of Birth?

Comment: Since you're currently learning database design let me share this link with you: https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

That will come in handy when you need to store some kind of hierarchical data.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps have something like this. I have not tested the code so please excuse any typos. The code is MS-SQL

```
CREATE TABLE tblUserDefinedEntity
(
    UserDefinedEntityID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO tblUserDefinedEntity
VALUES
(1,'Person'),
(2,'Business')

-- properties each entity can have.
CREATE TABLE tblUserDefinedEntityProperty
(
    UserDefinedEntityPropertyID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO tblUserDefinedEntityProperty
VALUES
(1,'FirstName'),
(2,'Surname'),
(3,'Address')

 --maps properties to entities EG a person has a firstname
CREATE TABLE tblUserDefinedEntityPropertyMapping
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    UserDefinedEntityID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblUserDefinedEntityID(UserDefinedEntityID),
    UserDefinedEntityPropertyID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblUserDefinedEntityPropertyID(UserDefinedEntityPropertyID ),
)

-- a person has a firstname, surname and address, a business has a firstname and address
INSERT INTO tblUserDefinedEntityPropertyMapping
VALUES
(1,1,1),
(2,1,2),
(3,1,3),
(4,2,1),
(5,2,3)

--all the available values for each attribute, eg all the firstnames, surnames and addresses
CREATE TABLE tblValue
(
    ValueID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Value VARCHAR(255),
    UserDefinedEntityPropertyID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblUserDefinedEntityProperty (UserDefinedEntityPropertyID),
)

INSERT INTO tblValue
VALUES
(1,'John',1),
(2,'James,1),
(3,'Jill',1),
(4,'Smith',2),
(5,'Jones',2),
(6,'123 Fake Street',3)
(7,'124 Fake Street',3)

--creating instances of your entities and assigning them values
CREATE TABLE tblDataEnty
(
    DataItemID INT,
    UserDefinedEntityPropertyMappingID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblUserDefinedEntityPropertyMapping(UserDefinedEntityPropertyMappingID),
    ValueID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblValue(ValueID),
    PRIMARY KEY (DataItemID, UserDefinedEntityPropertyMappingID)
)
-- we have added
-- john jones (no address)
-- james smith (124 fake street)
INSERT INTO tblDataEnty
VALUES
(1,1,1),
(1,2,5),
(2,1,2),
(2,2,4),
(2,3,7)
```